# Prevent child page from reloading in side iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have a web application which runs inside an iframe. If I zoom in/out in IE and Chrome, the application reloads and takes me to the start page .

Is there any solution for this?

What I have tried:

I am trying to put the following JavaScript code in the iFrame page:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return false; // This will stop the redirecting.
    }
```

An alert pops. I don't need this alert .

Comment: Can you post some more code about the iframe integration?

Comment: I found bellow code inside document ready event
function resizedw(appwidth) {
            var window_changed = $(window).width() != appwidth;
            if ($(window).width() != appwidth) {
                console.log(location)
                //location.href = location.href;
                location.reload();
            }
            past_width = $(window).width();
        } 
and location.reload(); reload the same page in mozzilla ,but in chrome and IE its reload the initial SRC page of the iframe .